# Save the data in a table in database according to the id created on different table in a laravel

Tags: laravel

I have an employee table which of course has its id and another table where the training detail of an employee needs to be stored (empty table).

I need to store the training details of an employee according to the employee id and also dor authenticates the user.

What is the code to write in an store function of a controller?
The training information is taken from a form type.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please try something yourself first. Then if you run into problems come back with a minimal code snippet that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

if there is a relation between them you can use `save()` or `create()` methods, something like this

```
use App\Models\Training;
use App\Models\Employee;
 
$taining = new Training(['key' => 'value']);
 
$employee = Employee::find(1);
 
$employee->trainings()->save($taining);
```

check this

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#the-save-method

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method

I hope it's helpful